# How can I fill empty table rows which references another table's column ID?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, hibernate

I want to fill out empty notification_settings for each user that already exists. IDs (PKs) are auto-generated by Hibernate in each table. Here is the user Table :

```
CREATE TABLE lottery_user (
    id int8 not null,
    email varchar(255) not null,
    password varchar(255) not null,
    notification_settings_id int8,
    role varchar (50) default 'USER',
    registry_date TIMESTAMP  default now(),
    primary key (id)
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_USER_TO_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS
FOREIGN KEY (notification_settings_id) REFERENCES notification_settings
);
```

And here is the notification_settings table which I need to fill out for users that don't have it filled out for them.

```
CREATE TABLE notification_settings (
 id int8 not NULL ,
 test1_events bool DEFAULT TRUE ,
 test2_events bool DEFAULT TRUE ,
 test3_events bool DEFAULT TRUE ,
 test4_events bool DEFAULT TRUE ,
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Basically, I need to use `"INSERT INTO notification_settings (test1_events, test2_events, test3_events, test4_events) VALUES (True, True, True, True)"` something similar to that. And of course, condition should be something like this "where these rows are empty for users". I can't seem to get Syntax right.

**BIG NOTE:** SQL code is for presentation purpose, so you can have an idea what kind of tables I have. I just need to get INSERT script right. Tables are working fine, just need to generate notification_settings values for users that already exist.

**Another Note:** Using Flyway, so it's not just about Hibernate. If that has to do with anything.

Comment: As you have added `DEFAULT` values to the table `notification_settings` they will always be `TRUE`. Just insert in the `id`.

Comment: IDs are auto-generated by Hibernate how can I go about that?

Comment: Could you explain your data model? In the current model, where `user` links to `notification_settings`, you would just need to set the default value for `notification_settings_id int8` to (one) id that contains `true, true, true, true`. Although I am not entirely sure that is what you are looking for. You probably want to use the userid in `notification_settings` instead of a new id. You can do it then with an `insert`-trigger on your `user`-table. And you could instead also add the 4 columns to the `user` table itself and not have the second table at all.

Comment: Nah, I don't need to use userId FK in `notification_settings`. I edited question a little bit, sorry for any confusion I have caused. I just need to fill out second table for users that already exist and don't have it filled it out. I already got several answers which might help. Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question how I dealt with it. Firstly, I insert IDs into `notification_settings` id, then I get those IDs and set them into `lottery_user` table's FK (`notification_settings_id`). Then I just delete unneeded IDs. Yea not perfect but it works.

```
INSERT INTO notification_settings  (id) select lu.id from lottery_user lu where lu.id not in(select ns.id from notification_settings ns);

update lottery_user lu set notification_settings_id = (select ns.id from notification_settings ns where ns.id = lu.id) where lu.notification_settings_id is null;

delete from notification_settings ns where not exists (select * from lottery_user lu where lu.notification_settings_id = ns.id);
```

Also, script to Alter Sequence for new Lottery_user entities.

```
do $$
declare maxid int;
begin
select max(id) from lottery_user into maxid;
IF maxid IS NOT NULL THEN
EXECUTE 'ALTER SEQUENCE notification_settings_seq START with '|| maxid;
END IF;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you just looking for:

```
INSERT INTO notification_settings (id)

SELECT       id
FROM         user
WHERE        id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM notifiation_settings)
```

You might be looking to insert into an identity field:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT my_table ON
```

Comment: It does the job just like the other answer , but notification_settings_id stays empty, it should be filled respectively with notification_settings.

Answer (score 1):

Since your foreign key constraint goes from notification_settings to user, the condition "where these rows are empty for user X" does not apply to your schema. On the other hand - "I want to fill out empty notification_settings for each user that already exists" can be done by using an `insert...select` construct:

```
set @rank=0
select @maxid = max(id) from notification_settings

insert into notification_settings (id)
select @maxid + @rank:=@rank+1 as rank
from user
where notification_settings_id is null
```

What is interesting is how you put those newly generated IDs back into the user table. Homework assignment for next time :)

Answer (score 1):

INSERT INTO notification_settings (id)

SELECT       u.id
  FROM         user u
  WHERE
    not exists (SELECT * FROM notifiation_settings ns where ns.id=i.id)

Comment: It does the job, but notification_settings_id stays empty, it should be filled according to notification_settings.

Comment: I can adjust it, however, notification_settings_id will always = user.Id in my example

Perhaps this is wrong. Is it possible for a user to have more than one set of notifications?